# Few dialog windows in Chrome don't show the buttons

Tags: google-chrome, vmware

I am running windows 10 VM and in the VM few of the dialog windows don't show the test and buttons properly. Texts some how are shown but buttons are not at-all seen.

I am talking about the form reload dialog windows which appear upon refreshing the screen.

I have re-installed the chrome and changed the color theme in case it helps but no luck so far.[enter image description here][1][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in one of the forum posts. Disabling the Hardware Acceleration option has helped me resolve this issue.

https://communities.vmware.com/thread/487812?q=Chrome%20browser%20issues